# problem understanding the template in c# and function

Tags: c#, templates, async-await, stride

the documentation [network](https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/api/Stride.Engine.Network.html) and the most importantly documentation: [SocketMessageLayer](https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/api/Stride.Engine.Network.SocketMessageLayer.html)

in SocketMessageLayer there is function which I don't know how to call:
`public void AddPacketHandler<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncHandler, bool oneTime = false)`

and this is how I was trying to call it:

```
    string str = "example";
    public SimpleSocket SS = new SimpleSocket();
    public SocketMessageLayer SML;
    
    
    
    public void Server(){
        //int port, bool singleConnection, int retryCount = 1
        SS.StartServer(21, false, 1);
        SML = new SocketMessageLayer(SS, true);
    }
    public void Client(){
        //string address, int port, bool needAck = true
        SS.StartClient("127.0.0.1", 21, true);
        SML = new SocketMessageLayer(SS, false);
    }
    
    
    
    public async Task SendMessage(string str){
        //public void AddPacketHandler<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncHandler, bool oneTime = false)
        await SML.AddPacketHandler<string>(SomeFunction("ClientSendToServer", await SML.Send(str) ), false  );
        //await SML.Send(str);
        
    }
    
    
    public void SomeFunction(string s, Task Tas){
        str = s;
    }
```

the problem is `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'` in Send Message

what I'm trying to do is send message to server or from server to client. and I have problem understanding the basics.

Comment: thanks but if I do that I get: `cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action<string>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of issues here.

`AddPacketHandler` expects a `Func<T, Task>` delegate as it's first parameter, but you are invoking `SomeFunction` rather than passing it as a delegate.

This means that you are attempting to pass the return value of `SomeFunction` i.e. void, which isn't allowed, hence the compilation error.

Furthermore, `Func<T, Task>` is a delegate that accepts a single argument of type `T` and returns a `Task`.

Your `SomeFunction` method accepts two arguments of type `T` and `Task` and returns `void`, so it cannot be converted into a `Func<T, Task>` and cannot be passed as the first parameter.

What you could do is change the signature of `SomeFunction` to this:

```
public Task SomeFunction(string s)
{
    str = s;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Which can be passed as follows:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string str)
{
    SML.AddPacketHandler<string>(SomeFunction, false);
    await SML.Send(str);        
}
```

And you probably want to pass `"ClientSendToServer"` to `SendMessage` rather than hardcoding it into that method:

```
await SendMessage("ClientSendToServer");
```

Answer (score 1):

First and most important: Why you **have** to call AddPacketHandler?

Looking at [this](https://github.com/stride3d/stride/blob/master/sources/engine/Stride.Engine/Engine/Network/SocketMessageLayer.cs/#L16), the PacketHandler is not mandatory, so you can not add it if you don't need it, although, for registering the packet handler, you can do in a lot of ways, here is three examples:

**Example 1**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static List<Func<object, Task>> _handlers = new List<Func<object, Task>>();

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // you handler code goes here
            Func<string, Task> func = (str) => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(str));           

            AddPacketHandler(func);
            await _handlers[0]("foo");
        }       

        public static void AddPacketHandler<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncHandler)
        {
            _handlers.Add((obj) => asyncHandler((T)obj));
        }
    }
```

**Example 2**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static List<Func<object, Task>> _handlers = new List<Func<object, Task>>();

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // you can create your handler here
            AddPacketHandler<string>(
                (str) =>
                {
                    return Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(str));
                });
            await _handlers[0]("foo");
        }

        public static void AddPacketHandler<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncHandler)
        {
            _handlers.Add((obj) => asyncHandler((T)obj));
        }
    }
```

**Example 3**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static List<Func<object, Task>> _handlers = new List<Func<object, Task>>();

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddPacketHandler<string>(SomeFunction);         
            await _handlers[0]("foo");
        }

        // you handler code goes here
        private static Task SomeFunction(string s)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(s));
        }

        public static void AddPacketHandler<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncHandler)
        {
            _handlers.Add((obj) => asyncHandler((T)obj));
        }
    }
```

The handle itself will be called by the library [here](https://github.com/stride3d/stride/blob/master/sources/engine/Stride.Engine/Engine/Network/SocketMessageLayer.cs/#L128)

This code is based on the source code that is in the docs you informed, is always cool to give a look at that and see what the funcion actually does if you encounter yourself in some situation like this.